# Xamarin Upload pictures with camera in Webview

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, android-camera

I've uploaded pictures with the WebView camera,but I want to upload two pictures,
the first image is uploaded but the second image is not uploaded why?
what do I need to do to solve this problem?
Comment if detailed information is required for the code.
My codes below

MyCustomwebviewRenderer.cs

```
 Control.SetWebChromeClient(new WebViewChromeClient((uploadMsg, acceptType, capture) =>
        {
            MainActivity.UploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                var i = new Intent(Intent.ActionCameraButton);

                //To set all type of files
                i.SetType("image/*");

                //Here File Chooser dialog is started as Activity, and it gives result while coming back from that Activity.
                ((MainActivity)this.Context).StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }
            else
            {
                File imgFile = new File("/sdcard/Pictures/Repair_Image.jpg");
                mCapturedImageURI = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new File(imgFile.ToString()));
                if (mCapturedImageURI != null)
                {
                    mCapturedImageURI.Dispose();
                    imgFile.Delete();
                }
                if (camera!=null)
                {
                    camera.Release();
                }

                File imageStorageDir = new File(global::Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(global::Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures),"");
                if (!imageStorageDir.Exists())
                {
                    imageStorageDir.Mkdir();
                }
                File file = new File(imageStorageDir + File.Separator +"Repair_Image"+ ".jpg");
                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.FromFile(file);

                Intent captureIntent = new Intent(Android.Provider.MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
                captureIntent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, mCapturedImageURI);


                ((MainActivity)this.Context).StartActivityForResult(captureIntent, MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }
        }));
```

And my Mainactivity.cs

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
    {


        imgFile = new File("/sdcard/Pictures/Repair_Image.jpg");

        mCapturedImageURI = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new File(imgFile.ToString()));

        // Handles the response from the FileChooser
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE && resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            if (null == UploadMessage)
                return;
            Java.Lang.Object result = intent == null || resultCode != Result.Ok ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.Data;
            UploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(result);
            UploadMessage = null;



        }

       // UploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I wrote it like this:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
       var file = getLatestFilefromDir("/sdcard/Pictures/CeptePortal/");
        mCapturedImageURI = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE && resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
            if (null == UploadMessage)
                return;
            Android.Net.Uri result = null;
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.Data;
            }
            try
            {
                UploadMessage.OnReceiveValue(result);
                UploadMessage = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
private Java.IO.File getLatestFilefromDir(String dirPath)
    {
        File dir = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = dir.ListFiles();
        if (files == null || files.Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lastModifiedFile.LastModified() < files[i].LastModified())
            {
                lastModifiedFile = files[i];
            }
        }
        return lastModifiedFile;
    }
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue but need to see the rest of the class that you have created - is it possible to share?

Comment: Sorry, I've stopped developing with Xamarin now and continue with Flutter.
Flutter is the best!